# Can I send a single BLE advertisement packet from android OS?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Can I send a single BLE advertisement packet from android OS? 
That means, in-between start and stop advertisement APIs, I should get only one advertisement packet.

Comment: I too have this requirement. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not even possible on the hci level. By timing your start and stop command, you could try to do this manually, and hope that exactly one packet will be sent, but it's not guaranteed to work, due to how the scheduler works.